# How to access Microsoft Graph DriveItem (Video) Content Stream for use with MediaPlayerElement (using Graph .NET SDK)

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Using the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK, I am trying to access the Content Stream of a DriveItem, which is a Video, so that it can be played in the UWP MediaPlayerElement. However, when deployed, the `MediaPlayerElement` displays:

> 'Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path'.

I can access the Microsoft Graph using the Windows Community Toolkit and have the `Files.ReadWrite.All` permission implemented. I have also got the `DriveItem` `id` as required.

```
private async void LoadVideo(DriveItem driveItem) {
    var graphClient = MicrosoftGraphService.Instance.GraphProvider;

    using(Stream responseStream = await graphClient
        .Me
        .Drive
        .Items[driveItem.Id]
        .Content
        .Request().GetAsync()) {
        var memoryStream = responseStream as MemoryStream;
        if (responseStream != null) {
            // Breakpoint on this line is reached after 
            // a substantial delay on the using statement 
            // line. At this line, the memoryStream has a value of 89400353.
            MyMPE.Source = MediaSource
                .CreateFromStream(memoryStream
                    .AsRandomAccessStream(), "video/mp4");
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The if statement always runs. When I place a breakpoint on the line beginning `MyMPE.Source…`, there is a substantial delay on the `using` statement before the breakpoint is reached. The MediaPlayerElement then displays the error 'Error:Unsupported video type or invalid file path' at the bottom of the player.

Comment: I don't believe the API supports streaming directly like this, also I don't believe the media player will follow the 302 redirect. You likely need to download the file and stream it from disk.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur thanks for your comment, I thought this might have been the case with the API, but it's a shame, maybe it'll be supported at some point in the future though.